# Error when assigning Flutter routes using {} notation

Tags: flutter

I'm doing The Complete 2020 Flutter Development Bootcamp with Dart, and this code is straight out of the video:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screen0.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/', (context) => Screen0(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The code isn't compiling with the error `The argument type 'Set<Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, Widget Function(BuildContext)>'.`

If I cast the routes object, so it's

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screen0.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/', (context) => Screen0(),
      } as Map<String, WidgetBuilder>,
    );
  }
}
```

The code compiles, but crashes when run, with the error `type '_CompactLinkedHashSet<Object>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, (BuildContext) => in type cast`

The videos should be fairly up-to-date, so this seems like a recent change. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or how I should be approaching this?

Version:

```
Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.9 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f139b11009 (5 weeks ago) • 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
Engine • revision af51afceb8
Tools • Dart 2.7.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because you didn't add a semi colon. Check the code below:
It works perfectly.

Replace this with your code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screen0.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/' : (context) => Screen0(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

You are missing a semi colon
I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

The problem is from your `route`. You used comma `,` instead of colon `:`

Here

```
'/', (context) => Screen0() //The comma should be a colon.
```

Replace the comma to colon like this...

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => Screen0()
      } as Map<String, WidgetBuilder>,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see it :D I've accepted Random Guru's answer as they were slightly before you, but thank you